# TABLE from database to ITEXT7 PDF generated with 3 column page setting

Tags: java, mysql, itext

Below is my code to set pdf in a three column page setting, now in the "insert code here" i want to insert a table from database. 
ex. list of fruits + prices.
so how could I do that?

```
    public void createPdf(String dest) throws IOException {
     //Initialize PDF document
     PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));

     // Initialize document
     Document document = new Document(pdf);

     //Set column parameters
       Rectangle[] columns = {
new Rectangle(20, 15, 175, 802),
new Rectangle(207, 15, 175, 802),
new Rectangle(394, 15, 175, 802) };
     document.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns));    

     PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
     PdfFont bold = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.HELVETICA_BOLD);
     document.setTextAlignment(TextAlignment.JUSTIFIED)
         .setFont(font)
         .setHyphenation(new HyphenationConfig("en", "uk", 3, 3));

    ????
    ???? INSERT CODE HERE

     //Close document
     document.close();
 }
```

here is the code on how do I get the table from mysql database

```
          try {
                    Class.forName(driver);
                    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, user, pass);
                    Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                    String zero = dates.getSelectedItem().toString();
                    String sql = "select fruits,price from fruitstable";
                    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
                    rs=pst.executeQuery();

                    Rectangle react = writer.getPageSize();
                    PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(new float[] { 5,5});
                    table2.setTotalWidth(527);
                    table2.getDefaultCell().setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
                    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph(""));
                    cell.setColspan(8);
                    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                    cell.setBackgroundColor(BaseColor.GRAY);
                    table2.addCell(cell);
                    table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);


                    while(rs.next()){

                        String v1 = rs.getString("fruits");
                        String v2 = rs.getString("price");





                        table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
                        table2.addCell(new Paragraph(""+v1+"", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,14,BaseColor.BLACK)));
                        table2.addCell(new Paragraph(""+v2+"", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,14,BaseColor.BLACK)));


                    }
                    table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,8,BaseColor.BLACK)));
                    table2.addCell(new Paragraph(" ", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_ROMAN,8,BaseColor.BLACK)));


                    document.add(table2);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }
```

now how could I do this? insert the table in a 3 columned page set so that I could manage to minimized the use of space of the paper..
 anyone? sorry for my bad english.
 please guide me or even help me.

Comment: That's different from the question in your comment where you asked for importing content that is originally stored in PDF files. Now you're talking about adding content that is stored in a database. Did I misunderstand the question in your comment?

Comment: Also: you are mixing code that only works in iText 7 (`document.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns)); `) with code that only works in iText 5 (there is no `PdfPTable` in iText 7). That can't ever work. Why aren't you reading the documentation? See http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks/chapter-5-adding-abstractelement-objects-part-2 if you want to know how to create a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing code that only works in iText 7 (`document.setRenderer(new ColumnDocumentRenderer(document, columns));` etc.) with code that only works in iText 5 (e.g. there is no `PdfPTable` in iText 7). That can't ever work.

Without testing if the code works, I adapted your iText 5 code to iText 7 code:

```
Class.forName(driver);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url+db, user, pass);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
String zero = dates.getSelectedItem().toString();
String sql = "select fruits,price from fruitstable";
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
rs=pst.executeQuery();

Table table = new PdfPTable(2); // create a table with 2 columns
// Why did you create a table with width 527?
// You are already divising your page in 3 columns.
// Why would you try to stuff a table that spans the complete width
// of a page in a column that is only 1/3 of a page???
table.setWidthPercent(100);
// Also: you were setting the colspan of a cell to 8
// in a table with only two columns. Why???
table.addHeaderCell("Fruits");
table.addHeaderCell("Price");
while (rs.next()) {
    table.addCell(rs.getString("fruits"));
    table.addCell(rs.getString("price"));
}
document.add(table);
```

If you want the table to use a different font, you can change the font like this:

```
PdfFont font = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
table.setFont(font);
```

You can also pass a `Cell` object to the table. For instance:

```
table.addHeaderCell(new Cell().add("fruits").setFontColor(Color.ORANGE));
```

This is all explained in the tutorial [iText 7: Building blocks](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-building-blocks)

Comment: Sir Bruno thank you for guiding me. I already did it thanks to you.

Comment: In that case, please accept the answer by clicking on the checkbox next to the score. (Now the unaccepted answer with a 0 score looks as if my answer wasn't helpful.)

Comment: i just add the other code that you give plus this one. thank you very much